# why alpha = 2/(span + 1) in pandas.DataFrame.ewm

Tags: python, pandas

In the document of pandas.DataFrame.ewm, it says alpha = 2/(span + 1). Don't understand why such formula exists between alpha and span.

1. Is it a convention or any sources to explain the formula?
2. Is it only an assumption/setting in pandas? actually it can be other formats, e.g. alpha = 4/(span + 3)?

Googled but there is no clue on that.

Grateful if someone could help! Thx.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html#pandas-dataframe-ewm

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a convention or any sources to explain the formula?

The `span` parameter is intended to roughly correspond to an N-period rolling average. Here's what [Wikipedia says about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Relationship_between_SMA_and_EMA):

> Note that there is no "accepted" value that should be chosen for alpha, although there are some recommended values based on the application. A commonly used value for alpha is alpha = 2/(N + 1). This is because the weights of an SMA and EMA have the same "center of mass" when alpha_EMA = 2/(N_SMA + 1).

So, the Pandas project did not come up with this formula - many others have used it.

> Is it only an assumption/setting in pandas? actually it can be other formats, e.g. alpha = 4/(span + 3)?

But would other ways of calculating alpha work too? You suggest 4/(N + 1), for example.

It's possible to do this - but it means that it approximates the N-period rolling average less well. Here's a practical example.

Below is a graph of US unemployment rate between 2005-2008. (Black line) Imagine you wanted to remove noise from this time-series. One way I could do that is to take a rolling 12-month average of the unemployment rate. (Blue line) Another possible approach would be to use an exponential weighted average. But how should alpha be chosen, in order get approximately a 12-month average?

Here are some formulas for alpha that you could use. There are three: the one Pandas uses, the one you suggested, and one I made up.

| N | Formula | Alpha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1/(N+1) | 0.0769 |
| 12 | 2/(N+1) | 0.1538 |
| 12 | 4/(N+3) | 0.2666 |

Below is a plot of what each looks like after smoothing.

[image: plot of ewm vs rolling]

You'll see that the green line ends up being similar to the blue rolling average, but is a bit more wiggly. The yellow line has a lower alpha, so it tends to put less emphasis on new pieces of data. It stays above the rolling average until 2008, then is the slowest to update when unemployment spikes. The red line tends to follow the original time series closely - it's pretty strongly influenced by new data points.

So, which of these alpha values is best? Well, it depends. High values of alpha are good at incorporating new data. Low values of alpha are good at rejecting noise. You'll have to decide what is best for your application.